# Keyboard Problem: Raspi through TightVNCServer and Screen Sharing on OSX site

Tags: keyboard

I watch my Raspi through Screen Sharing because I wanted to have a look at the new Mathematica Bundle. The problem is that I can't write [] brackets through the GUI, which sucks.

I edited /etc/default/keyboard to look like this:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="macintosh"
XKBLAYOUT="de_CH"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

rebooted and still can't write those characters (and by the way all which use the Alt key). I also ran

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

which didn't help either.

Any suggestions on the matter? I can't send Twitter messages from the Wolfram Language otherwise, which is a pitty :)

Comment: Not a perfect solution but can you copy and paste?

Comment: Good one I have thought of as well. But sucks in the long run. When you program and can't use [] and {} brackets you're in a lot of pain.